# ASP.NET Core Razor Application - How to create a click event for a button?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I created a solution for a razor application using a template.  I'm trying to build on the basic template to add custom logic.  Specifically, I'm trying to add a button to upload a file, but I can't seem to trigger the click event.

This is what I have for the button inside Index.cshtml:

```
@page
@model IndexModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "File Upload Demo";
}

    <button type="button" id="uploadsmall"
            onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("UploadSmall","IndexModel")'">
        Upload Small File
    </button>
```

And here's what I have the in Index.cshtml.cs file:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using Azure.Identity;
using Azure.Storage.Blobs;


namespace commDemo1.Pages
{
    public class IndexModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly ILogger<IndexModel> _logger;

        public IndexModel(ILogger<IndexModel> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        public async void OnGet()
        {
           Console.WriteLine('hello world');
        }

        public  void UploadSmall()
        {
             Console.WriteLine("in the click event handler");
        }

    }
}
```

When I run the code, the application is triggering the OnGet() in the model, but it never hits the UploadSmall()

**What I've Tried**

I also tried to "add" a controller called IndexController, and changed the default "create" HTTP POST method to UploadSmall().  Then I changed the name of the class in the Url.Action for the button to "IndexController" instead of "IndexModel" but that didn't change anything.

SOrry for the noob question but any help would be appreciated.

Comment: First, you need an HTML `<form>` if you are going to send (POST) any file. That button is being handled by Javascript and simply navigating users to `/UploadSmall` for example, and it's using GET method. I don't know how `Url.Action` works outside of ApiController, I gave up on it a long time ago and simply use fixed URL, but Razor Pages does not work like that. You need an `OnPost` to receive Post requests.

Comment: It is not good idea to use  java with the razor pages.  It is better to use a submit button. Othewise try to create an MVC or  an Angular application